# How can I make my sub-procedure dynamic to loop through a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a log that keeps track of what documents my employees have read. When they have read one in person, I manually change the color of the cell in my workbook. Then I have a macro that will look for any cells with the same document name as its value and will match the color. I want to be able to do this with all documents without having to write this macro for every document. I have tried for loops and do loops but I don't fully understand how they work.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1kq2.png) is a picture of my code, the first sub procedure *Match1* works perfectly fine for one document within a worksheet. *MatchAll* is where I had problems.

I get "Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed" a lot or "object variable or with block variable not set"

EDIT:

```
Public Sub Match1()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    
    firstAddress = Range("A10").Value

    With Range("C1:K500")
        Set c = .Find(firstAddress, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c.Interior.Color = Range("A10").Interior.Color Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                c.Interior.Color = Replace(firstAddress, firstAddress, Range("A10").Interior.Color)
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c.Interior.Color = Range("A10").Interior.Color
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

```
Public Sub MatchAll()

Dim a As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

 
For i = 8 To 197

a = Range(1, i)

firstAddress = a.Value

        With Range("C1:K500")
            Set c = .Find(firstAddress, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c.Interior.Color = a.Interior.Color Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    c.Interior.Color = Replace(firstAddress, firstAddress, a.Interior.Color)
                    Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c.Interior.Color = a.Interior.Color
         End If
        End With
        
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  One of the rules here is that you should post everything reasonably possible as text rather than as images.  This is because we cannot cut and paste an image into our own dev tools and test it.  However, if you post the code as text than we can format it for you and alos try it for ourselves.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I edited it and put the code in, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Your errors are probably coming from cases where `.Find(..)` or `.Findnext(..)` are returning `Nothing`, so after you `Set c = .Find...` you should check to see if `c Is Nothing`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung You're right when I hover over `Set c = .Find...` it says `c Is Nothing`. When I attempt to run it, it also highlights `a = Range(1, i)` saying `Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed`. Would this have to do with `.Find(..)` or `.Findnext(..)` returning nothing?

Comment: No, that's a different problem.  Try changing `a = Range(1, i)` to `a = Cells(1, i)`.  They're supposed to be the same function, but the doc says to do it this way.

Comment: Oh wait!  It should be `Set a = Range(1, i)` or `Set a = Cells(1, i)`.  Can't believe that I missed that.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I changed it and it still gives the same  `Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed` over `Set a = Range(1, i)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236351/discussion-between-jerrad-garrett-and-rbarryyoung).